# How to define the mapping for nested schema where same element name is used in parent and child?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to define the proper mapping for my JSON schema. but after trying all possible variable types and other attributes I have not been able to upload my JSON.

In my JSON I have a key "P" which is nested and complex in nature. this element is present in different sibling level objects and exhibits text,array,nested,object.

after my schema gets created when I try to load my JSON it fails with below error

```
$ curl -XPnST 'http://localhost:9200/ridev2/1' -d @v22.jso 
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't merge a non object mapping [EXPLA.SIDEHED.P] with an object mapping [EXPLA.SIDEHED.P]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't merge a non object mapping [EXPLA.SIDEHED.P] with an object mapping [EXPLA.SIDEHED.P]"},"status":400}
```

I am not sure what to do - if this issue doesn't get resolved I might have to switch to some other text search db. Please help me understanding where am going wrong.

My mapping JSON:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/ridev2?pretty'
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ridev2 -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "title21": {
      "properties": {
        "CFRDOC": {
          "properties": {
            "AMDDATE": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "FMTR": {
              "properties": {
                "EXPLA": {
                  "properties": {
                    "PRTPAGE": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "_P": {
                          "type": "text"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "SIDEHED": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "HD": {
                          "type": "object"
                        },
                        "P": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "_": {
                              "type": "text"
                            },
                            "E": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                "_": {
                                  "type": "text"
                                },
                                "T": {
                                  "type": "text"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The real JSON which am uploading:

```
{
  "EXPLA": {
    "SIDEHED": [
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "HOW TO USE THE CODE OF FEDERAL REGULATIONS",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": [
          "The Code of Federal Regulations is...atest version of any given rule.",
          "To det..ent of any given rule."
        ]
      },
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "OMB CONTROL NUMBERS",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": {
          "_": "The Paperwork Reductio...rdkeeping or reporting requirements.",
          "PRTPAGE": {
            "P": "vi"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "“[RESERVED]” TERMINOLOGY",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": "The term “[Reserved]” is used as a pl...dentally dropped due to a printing or computer error."
      },
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "CFR INDEXES AND TABULAR GUIDES",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": [
          {
            "_": "A subject index t...anua...also included in this volume ",
            "E": {
              "_": "Index and Finding Aids.",
              "T": "04"
            },
            "PRTPAGE": {
              "P": "vii"
            }
          },
          "An index to ...” is carried within that volume.",
          "The Fed....ral Register.",
          "A List of C..FR titles."
        ]
      },
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "SALES",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": "The Government Publishing Office (GPO) ... 979050, St. Louis, MO 63197-9000."
      },
      {
        "HD": {
          "_": "ELECTRONIC SERVICES",
          "SOURCE": "HED"
        },
        "P": [
          {
            "_": "The full text of the C...Phone 202-512-1800, or 866-512-1800 (toll-free). E-mail, ",
            "E": [
              {
                "_": "www.ofr.gov.",
                "T": "03"
              },
              {
                "_": "ContactCenter@gpo.gov.",
                "T": "03"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_": "The e-CFR is..rnment Publishing Office. It is available at ",
            "E": {
              "_": "www.ecfr.gov.",
              "T": "03"
            }
          },
          {
            "E": {
              "_": "January 1, 2016.",
              "T": "03"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues with json doc.

1) Path for the mappings object is wrong. If you want mappings to be enforced you will have to follow same json path for data.

This should be

```
{
    "CFRDOC": {
        "FMTR": {
            "EXPLA": {
                "SIDEHED": [
                    ....    
                    ....
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "EXPLA": {
        "SIDEHED": [
            ........
        ]
    }
}
```

2) inside `SIDEHEAD` nested_object `P` is defined as object in mappings and you are supplying a text value and this raise invalid mapping parse.

This should be

```
{
    "HD": {
        "_": "HOW TO USE THE CODE OF FEDERAL REGULATIONS",
        "SOURCE": "HED"
    },
    "P": {
        "_": [
            "The Code of Federal Regulations is...atest version of any given rule.",
            "To det..ent of any given rule."
        ]
    }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "HD": {
        "_": "HOW TO USE THE CODE OF FEDERAL REGULATIONS",
        "SOURCE": "HED"
    },
    "P": [
        "The Code of Federal Regulations is...atest version of any given rule.",
        "To det..ent of any given rule."
    ]
}
```

Make sure your json doc is a valid according to your mappings